# How can I read total number of the pixels in foreground and background of my image in C#?

Tags: c#, image, graphic

Basically I have written a code that creates image of a character (randomly generated). I have a problem how to scan the image line by line and read the total number of the foreground (text) and background (white) pixels in my bmp image and display the results to the user. here is part of my code:

```
Image bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.Clear(Color.White);
g.DrawString(randomString, myFont, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new PointF(0, 0));
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
bmp.Save(@"CAPTCHA.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Comment: Which part do you need help with? Scanning? Counting? Figuring out whether a pixel is background or foreground?

Comment: i am assuming the white color is background and any other color is foreground. i need all parts from scanning the image and count all the pixels in each line and the whole image please. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is simple - iterate over all the pixels in the bitmap, and if the pixel is white, increment your background pixel counter. After you're done, you can simply get the total amount of pixels (width * height) and do whatever you want with the background pixel counter value.

A simple (and very slow) code snippet that does this:

```
var backgroundPixels = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
  for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
    if (bmp.GetPixel(x, y) == Color.White)
      backgroundPixels++;
```

The notion of foreground and background is only there in your head. The resulting bitmap only has an array of pixels, each with a position and colour. You can assign a specific meaning to some color (white in your case) and say that it means the background - but that's it.

A good alternative would be to use a transparent bitmap, where there indeed is a special meaning for what you call background - transparency. In that case, apart from the colour, the pixel also has a notion of the degree of transparency (`Color.A`), which you can exploit. In that case, you'd do `g.Clear(Color.Transparent);` instead of using white, and when iterating over the pixels, you'd check if `bmp.GetPixel(x, y).A > 0` or whatever threshold you'd have for saying "this is the background". When you want to add the actual background *colour*, you'd paint this bitmap over a bitmap that's completely white and save that.

Comment: thank you for the code. (x,y) means either x in a row OR y in a column? or means if both pixles are white at the same time increase the 'backgroundPixels' by 1?

Comment: this is basically to count the total pixels in the background, how should i get the total pixels for the character in the image (my foreground) at the same time?

Comment: Luaan: its giving me error for "GetPixel" referencing error. should i include any reference?

Comment: @CowBoy If you want to know the amount of pixels per line, have a different counter for each line (ie. get some array and count there based on `y`). The total pixels for the characters are `totalPixelsInImage - totalPixelsInBackground`.